# How to group data using two columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, pivot, data-manipulation

I have sample data

```
s_name <- c("AL", "AL", "CA", "CA", "WI", "WI", "NJ", "NJ", "UT", "UT")
n_unit <- c(40, 30, 150, 110, 45, 80, 70, 40, 50, 90)
li_unit <- c(30, 30, 70, 40, 15, 80, 50, 40, 45, 45)
pv_lvl <- c("High", "Very High", "Medium", "Low", "Very Low", "Medium", "Very High", "low", "Very Low", "High")

mydata <- as.data.frame(cbind(s_name, n_unit, li_unit, pv_lvl))
mydata$n_unit <- as.numeric(mydata$n_unit)
mydata$li_unit <- as.numeric(mydata$li_unit)

mydata$per_li = mydata$li_unit/mydata$n_unit*100

print(mydata)
```

What I am trying to generate is a table that shows the percent of `li_unit` in each type of `pv_lvl` grouped by `s_name`.
Something like this:

```
s_name Very Low    Low    Medium   High    Very High
AL     0.00        0.00   0.00     75.00   100.00 
CA     0.00        36.36  46.67    0.00    0.00
WI     33.33       0.00   100.00   0.00    0.00 
NJ     100.00      0.00   0.00     0.00    71.43
UT     90.00       0.00   0.00     50.00   0.00
```

I tried the `group_by` function but did not get the desired result.
Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the standard `pivot_wider` way:

```r
library(tidyr)
mydata$pv_lvl <- factor(mydata$pv_lvl, levels = c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"))

pivot_wider(mydata, s_name, 
            names_from = pv_lvl, 
            values_from = per_li, 
            values_fill = 0,
            names_sort = TRUE)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  s_name `Very Low`   Low Medium  High `Very High`
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 AL            0     0      0      75       100  
2 CA            0    36.4   46.7     0         0  
3 WI           33.3   0    100       0         0  
4 NJ            0   100      0       0        71.4
5 UT           90     0      0      50         0
```

---

Note that you don't have to have to use `cbind` to create the dataframe,
`mydata <- data.frame(s_name, n_unit, li_unit, pv_lvl)` is enough. Also, I created a factor out of `pv_lvl` so that you can sort them as desired using `names_sort` in `pivot_wider`.

Answer (score 2):

Using reshape2

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydata,s_name~pv_lvl,value.var="per_li",mean)

  s_name High low      Low    Medium Very High Very Low
1     AL   75 NaN      NaN       NaN 100.00000      NaN
2     CA  NaN NaN 36.36364  46.66667       NaN      NaN
3     NJ  NaN 100      NaN       NaN  71.42857      NaN
4     UT   50 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN 90.00000
5     WI  NaN NaN      NaN 100.00000       NaN 33.33333
```

Note: you should fix some pv_lvl values (lower/uppercase), also you can factor it to have it in a specific order.